# Upgrading from Just-ice.jar to Icefaces 3.3.0 GA

Tags: java, icefaces-3

Currently the web logic portal application was using `Icefaces 1.8.2`. Now i am trying to upgrade it to `3.3`, but the application code was using `com.icesoft.faces.context.BridgeExternalContext` **getOriginalRequest** method to get the `HttpServletRequest` by using just-ice.jar provided by `Icefaces1.8.2`. Can any one guide whats the alternate class and Jar that i have to use in `Icefaces 3.3`.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
BridgeExternalContext bec = (BridgeExternalContext)ec;

Object originalReq = bec.getOriginalRequest(); 

if( originalReq instanceof HttpServletRequest){ 

 return (HttpServletRequest)originalReq; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ICEfaces 2.x and later all use the standard JSF Bridge, so BridgeExternalContext no longer is necessary.

HttpServletRequest requestObj = (HttpServletRequest)

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

String value =  (String) requestObj.getAttribute("property");

Would be how I would retrieve an object from the HttpServletRequest.